# How to verify Huawei ID on the server side using PHP

Tags: php, server, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-account, agconnect-functions

On the Android App, I managed to retrieve the token using AGConnectAuth. Now I would like to verify that token on the server-side using PHP. Any idea?

I tried call **https://oauth-login.cloud.huawei.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo** with the param **id_token=eyJhbGciOiJQUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IXXX** and it's returning the following error:

```
{
    "sub_error": 14004,
    "error_description": "",
    "error": 1400
}
```

Comment: may i confirm where is `id_token` obtained? From your example, this parameter is not in the correct format.

Comment: For some reason, the [error codes](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References/server-error-codes-0000001062371380) feature neither of the given error codes. Please provide the PHP code which produces this error response, else it's quite difficult to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since the returned error code cannot be explained by the documentation ...
you may not be posting as content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`;
most of the other API do require posting as `application/json;charset=UTF-8`.

I'm working on [it](https://github.com/syslogic/php-hms/tree/master/src/AccountKit), but don't have the that particular method implemented yet.
Maybe check within the next 1-2 weeks; I'm going to implement that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your ID Token looks quite a bit shorter than the example show in the documentation (2nd link) that has over 1000 characters. I recommend checking if your POST request was formatted correctly with the mandatory parameters and making sure your headers are correct.

Obtaining an Access Token https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References/account-obtain-token_hms_reference-0000001050048618
Once you have the correct ID token, here's the process to verify your token.

Verifying an ID Token https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References/account-verify-id-token_hms_reference-0000001050050577

Please share your PHP code and POST request so to help further if needed.